Can I use Monte Carlo when i can't use the exact test(fisher)?
I am currently conducting data analysis for my master’s thesis.
While performing cross-tabulation(chi-squared-test) analysis, I encountered some results where more than 50% (even 80%) of the expected frequencies are below 5, violating the assumptions of the chi-square test. The tables are 2x7 or 4x7 in size, and thus, exact tests cannot be calculated in SPSS.
In this case, is it appropriate to use the Monte Carlo method to calculate the p-value? IBM states that the Monte Carlo method can be used when Fisher's exact test cannot be calculated, but I understand that the Monte Carlo method is typically used for large datasets, which confuses me. I would appreciate your guidance on this matter.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/fisher-exact-test-rxc-table-fisher-freeman-halton-test

@Glen_b That really answers the question. If you add a couple sentences, why not make it an answer?

IMO, the link turns it into a pure-computing-implementation issue ('how do I do this in SPSS'). At the moment the only reason I see not to immediately vote to close is anticipating that the OP may edit the question in light of the link to something more nearly on topic.

I know how to perform exact tests in SPSS. However, even after setting the time limit to 30 minutes and running the exact test, I receive an error message stating, "Unable to open temporary file, calculation cannot be performed," and no value is calculated. It doesn't seem to be an issue with my computer's specifications, as I am using an Intel Core i5-10400 CPU and 16GB of RAM, which should be more than sufficient to run SPSS...

It seems that the exact message is "Cannot be computed because unable to open temporary file. And i don't use Mac, I tried to change the location of temporary folder.
